# Why is $\Pr(|X-Y|>t)\le\Pr(|X|>t/2)+\Pr(|Y|>t/2)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, inequality

I am having trouble proving the inequality in the title of this post.

This inequality is commonly used in Statistical Learning Theory, when proving Symmetrization lemmas. When used in such context, it usually takes the following form :

> $$\mathbb P\left(\left\vert\sum_{i=1}^n\varepsilon_i(f(X_i) - f(X_i'))\right\vert>t\right) \le \mathbb P\left(\left\vert\sum_{i=1}^n\varepsilon_i f(X_i) \right\vert>t/2\right) + \mathbb P\left(\left\vert\sum_{i=1}^n\varepsilon_if(X_i') \right\vert>t/2\right)$$

Where the $\varepsilon_i$ are i.i.d. Rademacher random variables (i.e. take value $\pm 1$ with probability $1/2$), $(X_i)$ are i.i.d. random variables and $(X_i')$ are i.i.d. copies of $(X_i)$ and $f$ is some deterministic function. The above inequality can be found, e.g., in the paper [A few notes on Statistical Learning Theory](https://maths-people.anu.edu.au/%7Emendelso/papers/summer02.pdf) by Shahar Mendelson (page 6), and is said to directly follow from the triangle inequality.

Although it looks very simple, I can't see why this inequality holds. Here is what I have so far :

First, $\mathbb P(|a-b|>t) = 1 - \mathbb P(|a-b|\le t)$. Furthermore, by the triangle inequality, it is straightforward to see that $\{|a|\le t/2\}\cap\{|b|\le t/2\} \subseteq \{|a-b|\le t\}$. We thus have the following bound
$$\mathbb P(|a-b|>t) \le 1- \mathbb P\left(\{|a|\le t/2\}\cap\{|b|\le t/2\}\right)$$
Now I'd like to have a bound of the form $1 - \mathbb P\left(\{|a|\le t/2\}\cap\{|b|\le t/2\}\right) \le \mathbb P\left(\{|a|> t/2\}\cup\{|b|> t/2\}\right) $ for the RHS of the inequality, from which I would be able to conclude by the union bound, but I can't prove the desired inequality...

It seems very elementary, what am I missing here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $\{|a|\leq t/2\}\cap\{|b|\leq t/2\}\subseteq\{|a-b|\leq t\}$, then you can take the complements of these sets and conclude that $\{|a-b| > t\}\subseteq \{|a|> t/2\}\cup\{|b|> t/2\}$. The desired inequality follows from that.

Comment: Can't believe I missed something so obvious. Thank you !